# Как скачать файл скрипта с сайта?

Tags: python, site

Стоит такая задача:
Написать программу на python, которая смогла бы скачать скрипт одной страницы сайта(бэк енд именно). Прошу помощи, как лучше это реализовать?

Вот страница, откуда я хочу скачать весь код: https://racebot.pw/app/req.php

Comment: Если веб-сервер не настроен отдавать содержимое скриптов, то никак

Answer (score 2):

Невозможно, погугли на английском, выдает пару ответов. Back End - серверная часть сайта, если бы ты мог скопировать эту часть - уже бы были сотни копий Youtube.